# visual-studio-code : failed to connect. is docker installed?

Tags: docker, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

my environment :
MacOS M1 chip
VSCode version 1.66.2 arm64
local installed docker version : 20.10.22

I have situations that docker is not working in VSCode.
I already installed docker in local. But when I'm trying to connect docker in VSCode, repeatedly asking install docker extensions. (but I do have docker already ). and if I do reinstall with following the VSCode, the docker version was broken (changed to intel chip docker).
Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somebody will have the same issue on Mac OS

I had docker installed and the error in Visual Studio Code:

```
Failed to connect. Is Docker running?
Error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

After I figured out the `Allow the default Docker socket to be used` option was disabled in Docker Desktop settings. When I have enabled it, everything started to work as expected for:

```
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

Wrong configuration in screenshots:

1. Failed connection

[image: docker failed connection]

2. Docker settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Docker Extensions` for `VS Code` have nothing to do with the Docker engine itself. They are like an additional layer of tools and commands over the installed Docker. E.g. they provide IntelliSense for editing Docker-related files, you can run Docker commands from F1 drop-down, etc. But you should be able to do all the required tasks even without `Docker Extensions`, e.g. from the `Terminal` in `VS Code`, but for this the path to Docker CLI (command line interface) should be added to PATH environment variable.

If you are getting *failed to connect* error then maybe Docker engine is not running. Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/ and https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/ about how to check if the engine is running and how to troubleshoot the issues.

If that doesn't help, please provide some specific error and steps, which led to it, then we'll try to find out.

Comment: Hello mike, thanks for the answer. By the way, I still faced this problems. 
1. I installed docker extension. but docker couldn't connect well : keep asking install docker even though local terminal docker working well. 
2. docker path is added. but not working. 
please let me know any idea..

Comment: Please check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/troubleshooting. Also I would try rebooting the computer. What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "is docker installed?" instead of "is docker running?", it's likely that `docker` is not in your PATH. Solution is very similar to the other solution. Either:

1. Add it to PATH manually (add `$HOME/.docker/bin`.)
2. Set "system" in the settings to allow it to be used by all users:
   [image: example settings]