# Error: Visual Studio Container Tools requires Docker Desktop for Mac

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, visual-studio-mac

I am having an issue with Docker and Visual Studio on my Mac.  I have Visual Studio 17.5.4 (build 8) and Docker Desktop for Mac 4.19.0 (106363) installed.

I have added Docker Support to my Web project and it added the docker-compose project and the Dockerfile file to the solution.  When I start Docker Desktop, then try and build the solution or the docker-compose project I get the below error in VS:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(5,5): Error: Visual Studio Container Tools requires Docker Desktop for Mac.  To get it, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847268

For more info, please see: https://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting (docker-compose)
```

If I run `docker --version` in terminal I get "Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a".  Docker Desktop runs the docker/getting-started app just fine so it seems to be set up ok.

I also created an new solution in VS with docker support and have the same error.

I've looked at a number of SO posts, most referring to VS Code on Mac or Windows and tried some of those solutions where appropriate but can't get this working.  Some of these suggested adding the below to the PATH variable:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Any help with where else I should be looking is appreciated.

Comment: The docker MSBuild target seems to look for the docker file in /usr/local/bin/docker and if that does not exist it will report the error you are seeing. I have an old Docker .app installed I have a symlink from /usr/local/bin/docker to /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker so creating this symlink if it is incorrect or does not exist may fix the problem for you.

Comment: @MattWard Looked promising but still get the same error unfortunately https://capture.dropbox.com/HUFmPyScm49L89O2

Comment: @guytz72 - were you able to resolve this? I am running into it and have tried all the remedies to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question, however I just ran into the same issue and thanks to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270449) to another question, regarding the same issue and VS Code, I was able to figure it out. In newer Docker Desktop versions you have to enable the default Docker socket and that is used by the Visual Studio Container Tools.

To fix this open the Docker Desktop Settings, navigate to the Advanced section and enable `Allow the default Docker socket to be used`.

Hope this helps anyone who will stumble over this issue.